# Test method with request object in symfony and phpunit

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-http-foundation

I have the class that returns values from HttpFoundation request object. I want to write tests for that class and I have problem. 
That is my class:

```
class RequestCollected 
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getUserAgent(): string
    {
        return $this->request->headers->get('User-Agent');
    }

    public function getUri(): string
    {
        return $this->request->request->get('uri');
    }
}
```

And that are my tests:

```
public function testGetUserAgent()
    {
        $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0';
        $request = $this->prophesize(Request::class);
        $request->headers = $this->prophesize(HeaderBag::class);
        $request->headers->get('User-Agent')->willReturn($userAgent);

        $collected = new RequestCollected($request->reveal());

        $this->assertEquals($userAgent, $collected->getUserAgent());
    }

    public function testGetUri()
    {
        $uri = 'test';
        $request = $this->prophesize(Request::class);
        $request->request = $this->prophesize(ParameterBag::class);
        $request->request->get('uri')->willReturn($uri);

        $collected = new RequestCollected($request->reveal());

        $this->assertEquals($uri, $collected->getUri());
    }
```

Error is same for both tests:
    Error: Call to a member function willReturn() on null

There is any solution for that? Or another method to test something what is using request object?

Greetings

Comment: Why are you doing $request->request->headers instead of $request->headers?

Comment: My bad. Now error is  "Error: Call to a member function willReturn() on null" like in second test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need use prophesy or mock object to test this simple class

```
public function testGetUserAgent()
{
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0';
    $request = new Request();
    $request->headers = new HeaderBag(['User-Agent' => $userAgent]);
    $collected = new RequestCollected($request);
    $this->assertEquals($userAgent, $collected->getUserAgent());
}
```

The only that you need is check if your class is getting the information for a valid request, sometimes things are simpler than we think :)